# camel timer - stacked events

Tags: timer, apache-camel

I have a timer I'm testing in camel:

```
<from uri="timer:testTimer?delay=120000&amp;fixedRate=true&amp;period=120000"/>
<inOnly uri="activemq:getTCdata"/>
```

I see that the events stack up if something else is going on at that time. I wonder if there is a way to cancel a new timer event if there is one already stacked. While this behavior doesn't get in the way of anything in the flow I have, I'd rather not have stacked timer events all running at once at a lather point. I looked at the camel timer documentation and didn't find anything for this purpose. I know that this is also the behavior of Java's Timer the camel timer is based on. I'd like to check if anyone knows of solutions in camel for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

See the `fixedRate` option
http://camel.apache.org/timer

Its the option from the JDK timer api, so you can find more detail about it there too. But setting it to true, means new task is only scheduled when the current task completed, so they always run with a fixed X period between them.

Comment: Awesome! I should be set then.